# Showing Memory Leakage Only on Device Test. Do't Know Why.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-leaks

[image]

Hi All,

In my iPhone Application when I run it on device showing these Error. So please tell me will these be the reason of App rejection?

Please tell me, why these errors are raising?

Here is Code i am using. Please take a look:

```
NSMutableString* s = [[[NSMutableString alloc]init]autorelease];
[s appendString: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"];
[s appendFormat: @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns=\"%@\">", ns];
if(headers != nil && headers.count > 0) {
    [s appendString: @"<soap:Header>"];
    for(id key in [headers allKeys]) {
        if([[headers objectForKey: key] isMemberOfClass: [SoapNil class]]) {
            [s appendFormat: @"<%@ xsi:nil=\"true\"/>", key];
        } else {
            [s appendString:[Soap serializeHeader:headers forKey:key]];
        }
    }
    [s appendString: @"</soap:Header>"];
}
[s appendString: @"<soap:Body>"];
[s appendFormat: @"<%@>%@</%@>", method,[params stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"], method] ;
[s appendString: @"</soap:Body>"];
[s appendString: @"</soap:Envelope>"];
return s;
```

Comment: Bunts you can edit your question.. :)

Comment: Sorry dear, everything seems right in your code. But i can assure you it'll not be the cause to your app rejection.

Comment: this issue not raising on simulator. so whats the reason behind .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableString* s = [[[NSMutableString alloc]init]autorelease];
[s appendString: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"];
[s appendFormat: @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns=\"%@\">", ns];
if(headers != nil && headers.count > 0) {
    [s appendString: @"<soap:Header>"];
    for(id key in [headers allKeys]) {
        if([[headers objectForKey: key] isMemberOfClass: [SoapNil class]]) {
            [s appendFormat: @"<%@ xsi:nil=\"true\"/>", key];
        } else {
            [s appendString:[Soap serializeHeader:headers forKey:key]];
        }
    }
    [s appendString: @"</soap:Header>"];
}
[s appendString: @"<soap:Body>"];
[s appendFormat: @"<%@>%@</%@>", method,[params stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"], method] ;
[s appendString: @"</soap:Body>"];
[s appendString: @"</soap:Envelope>"];
return s;
```

Here is Code i am using. Please take a look.

Comment: I suggest you should delete this answer.. as it is not an answer.. :)

Comment: This is not the answers, and you removed my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you created a NSMutableString. If you not using ARC, you have to release it.

Comment: ns, is that a NSMutableString?. If you have instance variables as NSMutableString, you have to dealloc them

Comment: can it be the reason for App rejection.?

Comment: I think your using more NSMutableStrings, for instance, the ns variable is that a NSMutableString?

Comment: In general: no. But if your device will run out of memory, and crash as a result of memory leaks, they will. Your only leaking some bytes.. But if you can fix it, fix it :)

Comment: there is only NSMutableString *s;

Comment: If your only call this method once, and not 1000x times your probably safe. Would be nice if you would mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: but i call it in to   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

Comment: They probably will not reject it, please use the V on the left of the original post, above the comments. Thanks

Comment: Can you transform your thank you in clicking the grayed V next to "I think you created a NSMutableString. If you not using ARC, you have to release it." answer. Thanks